# Long response time from Amazon's S3 bucket

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've started experiencing an unusual long response time (**15s**) for images in Amazon's S3 buckets. Most of the time is spent on **waiting**.

I run on **Heroku**.

This is the result of **Apache benchmark**:

```
Server Software:        AmazonS3
Server Hostname:        bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /4e846e6fb34c9490_unnamed.png
Document Length:        118768 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   81.125 seconds
Complete requests:      10
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      1191510 bytes
HTML transferred:       1187680 bytes
Requests per second:    0.12 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       8112.487 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       8112.487 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          14.34 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        8   10   2.6     10      17
Processing:   567 8102 7884.7  15572   15597
Waiting:      294 7807 7901.0  15297   15311
Total:        577 8112 7885.7  15581   15614

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%  15581
  66%  15586
  75%  15587
  80%  15598
  90%  15614
  95%  15614
  98%  15614
  99%  15614
 100%  15614 (longest request)
```

And the **request headers**:

```
Remote Address:54.231.15.17:80
Request URL:http://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/8118c4f0a203c368_roadmapimage.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://app-name.herokuapp.com/public/prism/7814? token=48890cb264&em=lili.test922@yopmail.com&fn=lili&ln=test922
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:577016
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Sun, 07 Dec 2014 13:23:11 GMT
ETag:"3709113ba6efc237617eda7e64afac89"
Last-Modified:Sat, 06 Dec 2014 00:52:29 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2:UeaGp+Ahxb2M4XQTFCZ3HHSYNend6RvO1QowbUzMJtyd82NyS7yrp86mydu23mYI
x-amz-request-id:70FD6E3158B45C6B
```

Comment: Try specifying full endpoint URL, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After endless talks with Amazon's support, without any progress to a real solution and many disappointed customers, the workaround was to add a **CDN** with its origin pointing to the S3 bucket. It improved the latency dramatically.

It's not a direct solution to the problem but it's the right way to serve static assets anyway.